# How can Chebychev's inequality give this (from Random Forests by Breiman)?

Tags: probability, inequality

I read **Random Forests** by Leo Breiman and found this on page 8: (the notation has been simplified):

We have $s = E(mr)$ and $s\geq 0$, then

$P(mr < 0) \leq P(\vert mr-s \vert \geq s) \leq \frac{var(mr)}{s^2}$.

Could someone help: how can we derive $P(\vert mr-s \vert \geq s)$ from $P(mr < 0)$ ?

Thank you very much.

Cheers,
Hendra

Comment: Hint: $\{mr\colon |mr-s| \geq s\} = \{mr\colon mr \leq 0\}\cup \{mr\colon mr \geq 2s\}$.

Comment: Thank You :) @DilipSarwate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$mr \lt 0 \implies mr \lt s \implies |mr -s|=s-mr$

so  $mr \lt 0 \implies |mr-s| \ge s$

so $\Pr(mr \lt 0) \le \Pr(|mr-s| \ge s)$.

Comment: Going from the first line to the second line doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Suzu Hirose: If $mr\lt 0$ then $s-mr \gt s$, and we know from the first line that if $mr\lt 0$ then $|mr -s|=s-mr$, so if $mr\lt 0$ then  $s-mr \ge s$

Comment: OK, but it seems easier to just say $|mr-s|=-mr+s\geq s$.